# how to get system lock and unlock time in my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I'm developing a work flow management system as a web application,i should get when the system get locked and when is unlocked.

Comment: where is ur code and what you've tried ?

Comment: I don't believe that Javascript has access to that low-level OS properties.

Comment: who ever using my web application , I should get them system locking and unlocking time. @Ahmad Alsanie